# How to redirect partner portal directly to Community Login Page with out Login into Partner Portal

Tags: partner, portal, redirect

How to redirect partner portal to Community portal Login page directly with out LogIn into partner Portal.

Hi All,
I have partner portal site url is like http://mycompanyname.dev.cs9.force.com/.

Current Functionality is: When ever user clicks on the above site url then the user will redirect to the partner portal login page.

Required Functionality is: When ever user clicks on the above site url then the user will redirect to Community Portal login page directly instead of go to partner portal login page.

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Aishwarya. What type of Community have you created? Is it a Partner Community or is it a Community other than a Partner Community? Further, does your Partner Portal still exist?

Comment: yes it is a partner community using Site. E.g support.cs20.force.com/Customerortal  And the partner portal still exist.

Comment: Just to confirm, you have a Partner Community and a Partner Portal using the same log-in controller Url. What's not clear to me is whether you're wanting to use both at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a simple URL redirect to accomplish this.

1. Go to Setup->Sites
2. Click on the Label of the old portal (the one you
   don't want users to use anymore)
3. Click 'URL Redirects'
4. Enter a new url redirect:

   - source: /
   - redirect type: Permanent (301)
   - Target URL: [your community url]